# JFrame Update fails because of sleeping Thread

Tags: java, thread-safety, frame

I just found out that the paint function of a panel doesn’t get called when the panels’s thread sleeps immediately after calling repaint.

This only calls the `paint(Graphics g)` function up to 10%:

```
    super.repaint();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

1: Why is that happening? I think I've read that swing uses only the component's thread (main thread).

2: How to fix this without calling the thread-sleep from the paint function?

Comment: Don't Block the UI Thread

Answer (score 0):

Most of Swing should only be use from the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). AWT Events, including painting, are dispatched on this thread.

It appears that the code is executing on the EDT. Use `javax.swing.Timer` (not any other `Timer` you may see - although `repaint` should actually be safe on a different thread) to set yourself a callback.